# Rederlivery of ActiveMQ dequeued message

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a Spring Boot application that is pushing JSON messages to a queue, and in the other place it is consuming those JSON messages using `@JmsListener`. Those messages are then send via HTTP Post request. The response code might be 200 and that's OK, but I would like to handle situations when client is down or just simply response code is different than 200.

Is there any mechanism that I could use for retrying the messages? Maybe I could push back the message at the end of the queue and retry them for lets say 3 times? Is there any internal ActiveMQ mechanism for doing that after message was actually dequeued?

Comment: Take a look at ActiveMQ's [redelivery policy](https://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. I looked into it but have no idea how to implement it within my scenario: Spring Boot app + embedded ActiveMQ and @JmsListener.

Comment: You haven't really provided any details about how you're configuring your application so it's impossible to provide a reliable recommendation on how to apply a redelivery policy.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for a transaction between the consumer and HTTP Post. JMS won't acknowledge the message off the queue until your code calls session.commit(). You can then call up to one HTTP endpoint and maintain reasonable transaction and single message delivery quality of service.

The key to making this self-healing is to detect invalid message payloads (ie bad JSON format or bad data) and move those messages into a DLQ.

Look into adding JMS local transaction support instead of using AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE

```
connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
```

Then in your psuedo-code:

```
  Message message = session.receive ..
  .. do valid message checks
  .. call HTTP endpoint..

  // now take action based on HTTP return code
  switch(httpReturnCode)
  case 200:
    session.commit();
  case .. invalid message returned from HTTP:
    .. produce message to DLQ for inspection
    session.commit();
  case .. http not available..:
    .. do some time delay, retry to http endpoint
```

Comment: It seems like in the case of "invalid message returned from HTTP" you'd want to invoke `session.rollback()` instead of `session.commit()` and let the configurable [redelivery policy](https://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy) take care of either redelivering the message or sending it to a DLQ. If there's no case where `rollback` is viable then using a transaction doesn't have much value.